# Search in NSArray VS search in CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data, ios7, nsarray

Which one is more efficient and recommended to use, I need to fetch a list of favorites from coredata and search it multiple times from uitableviewcell to see if it is favorite or not (exist in array or not).

With regard to scaling/performance what approach would be better?

1. Search core data table for favorites everytime if record is present or not
2. fetch in an array and search in nsarray everytime to see if record is there or not

Comment: I had the same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23154818/filtering-speed-uicollectionview-fetchedresultscontroller-vs-nsarray In the end I used all my core data objects in a new CollectionView and searched through the array, this resulted in a much much faster response time, even with CONTAINS searches.